# R get_ga function: filter component

Tags: r

I want to get Google analytic data from a specific list of cardnumbers. The component ga:dimension10 contains the cardnumbers. The following code works:

```
ga_datasubset <- subset(get_ga(id, Startdatum, Einddatum,
                               metrics = c("ga:sessions", " ga:pageviews","ga:sessionDuration"), 
                               dimensions="ga:dimension10, ga:deviceCategory, ga:medium", 
                               fetch.by ="day"),
                               dimension10 %in% Datatest[,1])
```

But I want to make this code without using the subset function. I tried the code below, but this doesn’t work.

```
ga_datasubset <- get_ga(id, Startdatum, Einddatum, 
                        metrics = c("ga:sessions", " ga:pageviews","ga:sessionDuration"), 
                        dimensions="ga:dimension10, ga:deviceCategory, ga:medium", 
                        filters ="ga:dimension10 %in% Datatest[,1]" ,
                        fetch.by ="day")
```

> Error: Invalid parameter: Invalid value 'ga:dimension10 %in% Datatest[,1]' for filters parameter.

Any help will be greatly appreciated